# How to access to the text inside a Swing JPasswordField object?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpasswordfield

In a **JFrame** class I have a **JPasswordField** object, something like this:

```
pswdTextField = new JPasswordField(20);
externalPanel.add(pswdTextField, "w 90%, wrap");
```

I try to access to its inserted content (the password inserted by a user) by the following lines of code:

```
char[] pswd = pswdTextField.getPassword();
System.out.println("Password: " + pswd.toString());
```

The problem is that when I go to print this content I obtain the following output: **Password: [C@d5c0f9** and not the inserted password

Why? What is it means? How can I obtain the inserted password?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: *"Tnx

Andrea"*  By 1400 rep. you should know better than to include noise in posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why? What is it means?

If you go through [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) than you got this reasons.

For stronger security, it is recommended that the returned character 
array be cleared after use by setting each character to zero.

> How can I obtain the inserted password?

You can get password by,

```
  char[] pswd = pswdTextField.getPassword();
  String password=new String(pswd);
```

Or, you can directly print on `System.out.print`

```
  System.out.print(pswd); // It override ...print(char[]) method
                          // without concat with another String.
```

**Edit**

Please note that, If you concat `char[]` with `String` than it will inherit `Object.toString()` method.

```
 System.out.print("Password: " +pswd);// It will print like Password: [C@d5c0f9
```

Comment: No, if I do char[] pswd = pswdTextField.getPassword(); System.out.println("Password: " + pswd); I always obtain thsi output: "Password: [C@7a19a37a"

Comment: but converting the char[] pswd into a new String object work well :-)

Comment: @AndreaNobili, Without concat password with String, you can print that.

Answer (score 2):

`pswdTextField.getText()` is what you were looking for. `toString()` will not return the text inside a `JPasswordField()`.

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:  getClass().getName() + '@' +
>   Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

so use

```
System.out.println("Password: " +pswdTextField.getText());
```

Comment: ok, it work but Eclipse say to me that the getText() method is deprecated, what have I to use?

Answer (score 0):

getText() is depreciated for JPasswordField

in Java source, its written above getText() definition

" For security reasons, this method is deprecated. "

so getPassword() is preferred.
The problem you are facing is that you are printing an array using System.out.println()
either create a string using that character array
or use for loop to access each element one by one

for(int i=0;i < charArray.length;i++)

System.out.print (charArray[i]);